# Burger Toggle only One Bar Changes on Hover

Tags: html, css, togglebutton

I'm currently working on a navbar for what's going to be my website, but I'm having problems with the toggle burger icon.

I would like for to have all three bars of the toggle button to change at the same time while hovering over it, but only of them changes at a time when I hover over it.

### **Relevant Code**

**HTML**

```
<div class='toggle-button' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
    <div class='bar' />
    <div class='bar' />
    <div class='bar' />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle-button {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: fit-content;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.toggle-button:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    margin: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    width: 25px;
}

.toggle-button .bar:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the selector you used is used for inheritance.

That, and your :hover should be on the .toggle-button class, otherwise the style will change when you *hover* on the bar and not the full div.

Original:

```
    .toggle-button .bar:hover {
       background-color: black;
    }
```

What you need:

```
    .toggle-button:hover > .bar {
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

Also, I changed the color to gray so the bars won't blend with the rest of the button.

If you need more information I'm happy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish is to change to color of the 3 lines `.bar` on hover.

You will need to do it as follows:

```
    .toggle-button { 
       border: 1px solid grey; 
       border-radius: 5px; 
       cursor: pointer; 
       display: inline-block; 
       height: fit-content; 
       transition: all 0.5s ease;
    } 
    .toggle-button .bar { 
       background-color: grey; 
       border-radius: 2.5px; 
       margin: 4px; 
       height: 4px; 
       width: 25px; 
    } 
    .toggle-button:hover .bar { 
       background-color: black;
    }
```